# Easy way to create a simple animation and trace path of a point?

Tags: animation

I need to create a simple animation like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aocKBYyjM0).

I know this video is Created in MicroStation, but i don't need a complicated program for this and i think a simple one will be enough.

I just need to add some points, lines and set rotation speed, direction and trace path of one our two points. In video above look at Venus path.

[image: look at Venus path]

Any suggestions?

Look at this image, Is there any program that lets me visually create something like this and trace orange dot path?

[image]

Comment: Your web browser?

Comment: I think the problem with the question is that your not specifying what your skill level is. This isnt particularly hard its just that it all depends on where you start and what you have access to. I mean yes processing easy, but then matplotlib for python is equally easy. But noncomplicated seem sto indicate you expect a lucky break

Comment: Your right, I'm familiar with HTML Canvas and using Js to draw on it and i worked with CAD and CAM programs but i don't think that this problem needs a very complicated designs and coding (maybe I'm wrong). If there is a program with a GUI that simply lets me create rotating objects around another one and trace one point, would be nice and easy. I'm searching and if not program available i will continue with Processing.

Comment: it does not its just that programs do not generally aim to be this simplistic. They need to be overall competent or there wouldnt be a program. I would invariably do this in maya but blender is also a good choice. Mathematica is also a good choice. After effects might work too. Anyway, complicated is not a big thing here. I tested this and got it working in 15 minutes in maya, and 20 in mathematica. But then both of these apps have a 3-12 month learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was me I'd be 100% doing this with [Processing](https://processing.org). Processing is a Free / Open source programming environment / language that lets you easily make parametric animation like this. If you have the maths behind the curve sorted then implementing it as a processing sketch would be fairly straightforward.

A good starting point would be this sketch: https://processing.org/examples/sinewave.html
https://processing.org/examples/sinewave.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i think Processing is one of the best options for my request. But for a simple line that attached to a circle that rotate around another circle and another object is a little bit complicated and i think maybe a GUI would be easier. I'm familiar with programing and searching for an easier way if exist and if not I'll definitely back to Processing.

Comment: It could also be done with After Effects, but that would also require expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Easy is subjective, but using [Solvespace](https://solvespace.com/ref.pl) may allow you to accomplish your objective. The included link has a section about three-quarters of the way down referencing the trace point feature of the program.

Solvespace is a multi-platform, free program that allows for parametric designs in 3D but will function fine for 2D projects such as this.

[image: solvespace tracer]

This image from the linked site shows a 4 bar linkage with length parameters applied.

Comment: Animation though?

Comment: screen recorder?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not have animation function, And for screen recording i must change points location manually to trace and one point at time